# MySQL best way to exit a transaction?

Tags: mysql

I have a program starting a transaction and doing a lot of things. In the end I commit. In case of error, I want to rollback and save the error.

I am doing the following:

```
1) ROLLBACK;
2) START TRANSACTION;
3) add the error to the database
4) COMMIT;
5) exit
```

Is this good idea or it's better to start a new connection and never do rollback or commit on the old one?

If I never commit, where are my data? What happens to them?

Comment: If you never commit - then it's rolled back automatically as soon as your connection is terminated

Comment: If I never terminate the connection and my c++ program dies or crashes, then what?

Comment: then the connection is terminated. Mysql doesn't actually care what was the reason of a connection loss.

Comment: there is a function terminating the connection `mysql_close(mysql);` if I never use this function because my program crashes before calling the function, how the connection is terminated?

Comment: who will maintain the connection if your process has died?

Comment: the docs specify a huge timeout, 28800 seconds. All the time till the timeout, does the server keep the connection open?

Comment: I'm sure it depends on your OS. Will it keep the network socket for the process that exit without releasing it?

Comment: I see. So, with this in mind, is the 1st option better than the 2nd?

Comment: I think so. I don't see a reason to establish the second connection to the database while you already have one (in this particular case).

Comment: Thanks a lot. As a drawback if the transaction is huge, the rollback will take time, right?

Comment: Honestly - I don't now about mysql in particular. But from what I know about MVCC it should be reasonably cheap.